# Maven parallel download dependencies in same group

Tags: maven, maven-3

We use the maven dependency plugin (with maven3) to unzip dependencies at runtime for running a set of tests. However, because the number of dependencies and their size is large it can take upto 30 minutes for the download to finish (not all teams are on LAN). I checked with the maven docs and maven only downloads dependencies that belong to seperate groups in parallel. Is there any way that I can force maven or maybe the maven dependency plugin to download these dependencies in parallel?

Comment: Why do you redownload them? This makes no sense. If you have this performance issue, set up a Nexus repo manager.

Comment: We redownload them because they are snapshots...And we do download them from our internal nexus, except that the internal nexus download is not as fast as we'd like it to be primarily because it's located in a different location and the download takes places over the internet and not the LAN.

Comment: Well, the mini guide says that only [diff. groups](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html#Configuring_Parallel_Artifact_Resolution) are parallizable. I would do this:

1. Open a ticket for the dependency plugin
2. use an intermediate Nexus server

Comment: I'm guessing this is long solved for the OP but for future reference- Why not break your one internal mega-group to sub-groups? This might be a wise move just for documentation reasons (different groups represent different domains).

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to use

```
mvn -T3.0C phase
```

Comment: Karl-Heinz, this will parallize the build not the download.

Comment: The project is not multi-module. We use it to run integration tests so it's just one big project. I just tried this setting and it does not work. Also, maven raises a warning saying that the dependency plugin is not threadsafe.